# How to avoid click on <input> within an <a> from triggering click event on <a> without Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Given some HTML that looks like this:

`<a><label><input type="checkbox" /></label>link text</a>`

How, without coding, can I avoid a click on the `input` checkbox from triggering a click event on the `a`?

I'm using the `label` to enlarge the checkbox click target, and for reasons not worth going into, I *need* the `input` to be inside the `a` tag. I've tried setting `z-index` on the `label` and `input` to a higher value than the `a`, but that makes no difference.

The only method I've thought of is to track whether the `input` is being checked and, if so, ignore a click on the `a` (I am handling clicks on the `a` via jQuery anyway). Here's a full example, with HTML, CSS, and Javascript (jsFiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/forgetcolor/wQEjk/):

HTML:

```
<a><label><input type="checkbox" /></label>link text</a>
<div id="output"></div>
```

CSS:

```
label {
    padding:5px 15px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
a {
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:#eee;
}

a:hover { background-color:#ddd; }
#output { margin: 10px; }
```

Javascript:

```
var checkboxclicked = false;

$('a').click(function() { 
    if(checkboxclicked) return;
    $('#output').text("link got click");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#output').text("");
    }, 500);
});

$('input, label').click(function() {
    checkboxclicked = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        checkboxclicked = false;
    }, 250);
});
```

With this example, I get what I want---meaning that a click anywhere within the large target of the `label` tag triggers ONLY a click on the checkbox, while a click on the `a` outside of the `label` triggers a click on the `a` only.

But I can't help thinking there's a way of doing this purely in CSS. Is there?

Comment: Do you want to handle a click event only when `link text` got clicked using `jQuery` ?

Comment: yes, i'm only handling clicks via jQuery for the `link text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this entirely in CSS.  You'll need to use `stopPropagation` to keep the event from bubbling up to the `a`.

CSS is built to describe how a web page *looks*, not how it works.

Comment: ah, okay, that works nicely and is definitely less messy than my solution. forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/forgetcolor/caYtF/

Answer (score 1):

> You mentioned in comment: yes, i'm only handling clicks via jQuery for the link text

In this case, you may try this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wQEjk/6/)) :

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) { 
    if($(e.target).context.tagName != 'A') return;
});
```

So, `click` will take effect only when `lnk text` is clicked.